# django ManyToManyManager returns empty list in post_save

Tags: python, django

I have a post_save signal connected to my model (Invoice - that has cases=ManyToManyField(Case)). But it looks like it is not able to get the actual saved values!! When I create an Invoice object, the function below is called and cases.all() return empty list, even though the cases ARE saved and shown in GUI and are in DB.

```
  @receiver(post_save, sender=Invoice)
    def set_invoiced_to_jobs(sender, **kwargs):
        db_obj = sender.objects.get(pk=kwargs['instance'].pk)
        if kwargs['created']:
            print db_obj.from_date
            print db_obj.cases.all()
```

Comment: This happens when you save a new object? In that case it cannot have any related object...

Comment: aaa thanks... I think I found my answer